# Accessing Select Text Value from Formik Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, formik

I am using the following code from a tutorial as a re-usable component for a Material-UI select:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const SelectWrapper = ({
  name,
  options,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);

  const handleChange = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const { innerText } = evt.nativeEvent.target;
    setFieldValue(name, value);
  };

  const configSelect = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    select: true,
    variant: 'outlined',
    fullWidth: true,
    onChange: handleChange
  };

  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configSelect.error = true;
    configSelect.helperText = meta.error;
  }

  return (
    <TextField {...configSelect}>
      {Object.keys(options).map((item, pos) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={pos} value={item}>
            {options[item]}
          </MenuItem>
        )
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default SelectWrapper;
```

When using this Select.js component within my App.js, i.e.:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Select
    name="country"
    label="Country"
    options={countries}
   />
</Grid>
```

is there  anyway I can also access the text value from

`const { innerText } = evt.nativeEvent.target;`

within the App.js component as I also need to get the Country name/text in my select list?

I just need to retrieve the text value from the selection the user made and store it in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

1. Define a state in your app.js file to hold the innerText value from the child component (Select.js in this case).

`const [innerTextSync, setInnerTextSync] = useState('')`

2. Define a function that changes the state in your app.js:

`const updateInnerTextSync=(input)=>{setInnerTextSync(input)}`

3. Pass this function as a prop into Select.js

```
<Select
    name="country"
    label="Country"
    options={countries}
    updateInnerTextSync={updateInnerTextSync}
/>
```

4. Within the handleChange function in Select.js file, update the app state by calling the function you passed in earlier.

```
const handleChange = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    const { innerText } = evt.nativeEvent.target;
    setFieldValue(name, value);
    updateInnerTextSync(innerText)
  };
```

Now the innerText should be available in ur app file.

Comment: Excellent work - that did the trick. Just one note is that I also needed to pass `updateInnerTextSync` into the Select.js component as a prop, i.e. `const SelectWrapper = ({
  name, options, updateInnerTextSync, ...otherProps`

Comment: As I am new to React, is this the only means of passing a value back from `Select.js` back into `App.js` ?

Comment: This is the only means I'm aware of.

Comment: just another question, I have a few calls to the use Select.js but I don't need to retrieve the innerText value for all the select components. How am I able to still call `<Select
    name="country"
    label="Country"
    options={countries}
    updateInnerTextSync={updateInnerTextSync}
/>` and not requiring `updateInnerTextSync` as at the moment, I am getting an error as itis expecting this prop?

Comment: Comment out where updateInnerTextSync() is been called in the handle change function.
Also you can exclude it from the properties passed into the <Select  /> tag.

Comment: I actually tried the latter, that is, removing it from the properties passed into the <Select />  tag and it gave me an error. Just wondering if I am able to pass a null prop/value into the <Select /> tag for this prop?

Comment: No it will throw an error.
That's because the last line in the `handleChange` function is calling a property that is not defined or passed in at the top level..