# Using input state in different components

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I want to use the state of the input in another component in React. So I have a component and in this component, I have a form.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

function Jumbotron() {
  const [inputFrom, setInputFrom] = useState("");
  return (
    <Form className="shadow p-3 mb-5">
      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Title</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter input"
          onChange={(event) => setInputFrom(event.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default Jumbotron;
```

So I want to use the 'inputFrom' in other component and I just want to show it. I will do it in several components so could you give me an advice about it?

```
import React from "react";

    import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
    function Checkout() {
      return (
            <Container>
              <div className="shipment-info">
                <div className="basic">
                  <div className="col-2 title">From</div>
                  <div className="col-4 info">{inputFrom}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Container>
      );
    }
    
    export default Checkout;
```

Comment: You can pass the state down as props to a child component

Comment: Where do you want to place the `<Checkout />` component?

Comment: Are they sibling components?

Comment: They are two different component. There is an input field in Jumbotron and after I took it I redirect to another page and I want to use the input there.

Comment: We don't seem to understand one another. Imagine your app as a tree of React elements. Where in that tree do you want to place `Checkout` (relative to `Jumbotron`)?

Comment: I can say they are siblings actually. I will use them on the same page

Comment: You can reference this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66997319/accessing-select-text-value-from-formik-select/66997599#66997599], the solution is similar to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down the prop to another component like so

```
<NextComponent propYouWantToPass={inputFrom} />
```

and use it in the next component like props.propYouWantToPass, assuming you got the props in the next component settings props as a parameter

```
const NextComponent = (props) => {

return(
<View>
<Text>{props.propYouWantToPass}</Text>
</View>
)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other already said, if you are planning to use `Checkout` component inside `Jumbotron` component as a child.
The solution is easy, you just pass `inputForm` as prop to `Checkout` and receive or inherit from `Jumbotron`

Could be something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Checkout } from "./Checkout";

function Jumbotron() {
  const [inputFrom, setInputFrom] = useState("");
  return (
   <>
    <Form className="shadow p-3 mb-5">
      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <Form.Label className="form-subtitle">Title</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter input"
          onChange={(event) => setInputFrom(event.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
{/* <-- give any name instead "inputData" */}
    <Checkout inputData={inputForm} /> 
   </>
  );
}

export default Jumbotron;
```

Found your `inputForm` on `Checkout` as `props.inputData`

*Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component